# how to validate an address of solana by using dart?

Tags: solana-program, web3.js, solana-wallet-adapter, rpc, jsonrpc-api

i need validate solana address for integration in my project

Is there a public API for this?

Answer (score 1):

In case you're just looking to verify if the Solana address is "correctly formatted", you just need to validate if it's on the Ed25519 elliptic curve.

You can find a helper function within the `solana` package maintained by the espresso cash team: [isValidAddress](https://pub.dev/documentation/solana/latest/solana/isValidAddress.html).

And here is a code implementation of the `isValidAddress` from the [espresso cash GH repo](https://github.com/espresso-cash/espresso-cash-public/blob/master/packages/solana/lib/src/helpers.dart)

```
/// Returns true if [address] is a valid ed25519 point encoded to base58.
bool isValidAddress(String address) {
  try {
    final data = ByteArray.fromBase58(address);

    return isPointOnEd25519Curve(data);
  } on Exception {
    return false;
  }
}

// Returns whether the point [data] is on the ed25519 curve.
bool isPointOnEd25519Curve(Iterable<int> data) {
  if (data.length != 32) {
    throw const FormatException(
      'invalid length, decoded address is not 32 bytes long',
    );
  }
  try {
    final compressed = CompressedEdwardsY(data.map(BigInt.from).toList());
    final point = compressed.decompress();

    return !point.isSmallOrder();
  } on FormatException {
    return false;
  }
}
```